# How to write test class for triggers

Tags: trigger

```
@isTest
private class Updatechildrecord  {
   public static testmethod void Updatechildtest()
   {
        List<Contact> Conlist = new List<Contact> ();
         Account a;
        for(Contact c : [SELECT Name,Id,Phone From Contact Where AccountId IN: Trigger.New]) {
        system.assertEquals('', a.BillingAddress);
        system.assertEquals('',a.BillingCity);
        system.assertEquals('', a.BillingState);
        system.assertEquals('',a.BillingPostalCode);
        system.assertEquals('',a.BillingCountry);           
      Test.startTest();
       try
       {
           Update Conlist;
       }
       catch(Exception ee)
            {
            }
             Test.stopTest(); 
        }      
    }
}
```

I had tried my code for updating mailing address of contact from account. Am facing an error please help me to solve that error. Thanks in Advance.

Error: Comparison must be compatible types: String,system.Address

Comment: Are you posting under multiple Salesforce Stack Exchange accounts? If so, please use the Contact link at the bottom of every page to have your accounts merged by the Community Team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you have different type vars in `expected` and `actual` in an assertion.

This line is the problem:

```
system.assertEquals('', a.BillingAddress);
```

In your code you are trying to assert BillingAddress against a string. But BillingAddress is a compound field. You cannot test like this. You need to check its contents one by one like you do in the next several lines.

Just remove that line. Other checks should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straightforward, really.

Data of type `String`, like `'this is a string'` or `' '`, cannot be compared to Data of type `System.Address` (which is what `BillingAddress` is).

`System.assertEquals()` is the thing performing the comparison.

Similar to your previous question, the solution here is to stop using the composite address field, and instead use its constituent fields (`BillingStreet`, `BillingCity`, `BillingState`, `BillingPostalCode`, and `BillingCountry`)

### You have other problems beyond this, though

- Trigger context variables are not available in unit tests (well, the code may compile, but I'd imagine the values stored will be null)
- Your assertions are trying to use address data from an Account, but you never query for an Account (or initialize the variable you're trying to use, for that matter)
- I'd think that if you're iterating over `Contact` records, you would
  like to make assertions on the data stored on those Contacts
- You're swallowing an exception. This is bad and counterproductive. Unless you're testing that a *specific* type of exception is being thrown, you want an exception to cause your test to fail.